# Vuetify - How to loop through multiple custom components in a carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, carousel

I was wondering if it is possible to loop through multiple custom components in a carousel in Vueitfy?

I have imported and registered three components in my carousel.vue file below, however, I am not sure how you can loop through all the registered components in the v-carousel-item tag.

What I have in my carousel so far:

```js
<template>  
    <v-carousel
        hide-delimiter-background
        delimiter-icon="mdi-minus"
        width="100%"
        height="700"
    >
        <v-carousel-item
            v-for="(component, i) in components"
            :key= i
            reverse-transition="slide-fade"
            transition="slide-fade"
        >   
        </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
</template>  

<script>
import Carousel_s1 from './Carousel_s1.vue'
import Carousel_s2 from './Carousel_s2.vue'
import Carousel_s3 from './Carousel_s3.vue'

export default {
    name: 'Carousel',
    components: {
        Carousel_s1,
        Carousel_s2,
        Carousel_s3,
    },
(continue my code ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `v-carousel-item` you can use Vue's dynamic component mechanism to display the correct one:

```
<v-carousel-item
  v-for="(component, i) in components"
  :key="i"
  reverse-transition="slide-fade"
  transition="slide-fade"

  <component :is="component"></component>
</v-carousel-item>
```

(BTW, you also should wrap your `key` value in quotes, as I did in my sample code)

Please note that this is not a Vuetify-specific feature but works in all Vue code :)

Comment: Did a minor twist and worked! Oh my god! Thank you so much dr_barto. Not sure if this is too much to ask for, when you have a chance, could you please explain more on the code you provided? Specifically -> :is="component" What is it doing in the code?


The twist: I imported all the custom slides and put them into an object and put it under  the Data section like this:

data: () => ({
    components: {
        Carousel_s1,
        Carousel_s2,
        Carousel_s3,
    },
  }),
};

Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Well, apparently Stack overflow took out all the spaces from my previous comment, so the code part looks really confusing. Sorry about that! But, yeah, basically, I wrapped all my slides into a object and put it under the Data section.

Comment: Glad to help :) You can find the official docs here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
In short, Vue's `component` is kind of a meta-component; I think of it as a placeholder for another component, and use it if the specific type of component is decided at runtime (or changes at runtime). You provide the concrete component via a binding (`v-bind:is="MyComponent"`, or using the shortcut `:is="MyComponent"`). BTW, you don't have to provide the component object, you can also use its name if you registered the component.